# Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/argparse/

Tags: artifactory, argparse, pipenv

I try to get a package from jFrog artifactory which has such requirements:

```
Jinja2~=2.10.3
PyYAML~=3.13
argparse~=1.4.0
requests~=2.19.1
```

I've successfully installed all these packages. They've appeared at Pipfile.
So after that, when I'm trying to fetch my target package from artifactory, I receive ResolutionImpossible error with descriptions:

> The conflict is caused by:
> my artifatory package name depends on argparse~=1.4.0

I checked `pip list`, it doesn't contain this argparse package, but when using `pip show argparse` it shows the description of it (name, version, summary, home-page, author, license, location, etc.)

How can I resolve this conflict?

Comment: argparse is part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) in python, you don't need to install it from PIP unless you're using python <3.2

Comment: @Alex Ok. I tried not to install argparse, but there was the same error with packages conflict. 
How can I fetch the library in the right way without that error?

Comment: That depends on what Python versions you are wanting to support, if you need to support Python < 2.7 or < 3.2 then you should specify [platform specific dependencies](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#platform-specific-dependencies) (I'm assuming you're using setuptools for your package). If you don't need to support old Python versions you should remove the `argparse` requirement.

Comment: @Alex I am not owner of the artifactory library, I'm just a user. I wanna use this library with `import` statement.
On my machine installed Python 3.7.

Comment: I would contact the package author about this as they may want to fix this. You can try installing without dependencies like so: `pip install --no-deps <package-name>` you may then need to manually install the other dependencies.

Comment: @Alex thanks. It was successfully installed with no dependencies